# Phonegap enabling push notifications on device

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I'm having trouble getting my PhoneGap app to register iOS devices for push notifications. Meaning when someone downloads the app for the first time they aren't being prompted to allow push notifications. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Push notification plugin can be used [from here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)   :

In Config.xml :

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
   <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

In index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
```

Comment: im using PushNotification.js but im still not getting prompted when I download the app on new devices. Is there something I'm missing?